# awk パターンを変数で動的に設定できるのか

Tags: awk

単純な変数展開ではなく

```
echo -e 1 2 3\\n4 5 6\\n7 8 9 |
awk $1==1,$2==2,$3==3"
```

とすると、当然1行目の1 2 3が取得できますが
ここでパターンを変数をつかったらときどうやって取得できるでしょうか？

具体的に
変数`aa="\$1==1,\$2==2,\$3==3"` 注意点としては`$n`や 等号 も変数に含めます。 
`awk 'eval aa'` ←のようなことをして、上記と同じ結果をえるにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

```
awk  -v a1=1 , a2=2,a3=3'$1==a1,$2==a2,$3==a3'
```

のような単純なことではない点を再度申し上げます。

Comment: 「パターンを変数を使う」というのがどういう動作をしたいのかよく分からないので、具体的にどのようなパターンにマッチさせたいのか追記してくださいませんでしょうか？

Comment: まず、条件式をシェル変数として定義して( `cond='$1==1&&$2==2&&$3==3'`)、`printf '1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9\n' | awk "$cond"`

Answer (score 1):

質問されている方の例とおり、条件式をシェル変数condに代入し、$condで参照すればよいと思いますが、いかがでしょうか。

```
cond='$1==1&&$2==2&&$3==3';printf '1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9\n' | awk "$cond"
```

【結果】

```
1 2 3
```

Comment: 失礼しました、質問者ではなく、 metropolisさんが回答されていました。